# Amazon post product with more marketplace Ids

Tags: laravel, http-post, amazonsellercentral

I am trying to post product on more marketplaces, but it returns error:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Invalid request parameters",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
```

If I send only one ID, it works `(for example just 'marketplace_ids' => ['A1PA6795UKMFR9'])`:

```
$specificationNewFeed = new CreateFeedSpecification([
      'feed_type' => 'POST_PRODUCT_DATA',
      'marketplace_ids' => ['A1PA6795UKMFR9', 'A1RKKUPIHCS9HS', 'A13V1IB3VIYZZH', 'AMEN7PMS3EDWL', 'A1805IZSGTT6HS', 'A1F83G8C2ARO7P', 'APJ6JRA9NG5V4', 'A2NODRKZP88ZB9', 'AE08WJ6YKNBMC', 'A1C3SOZRARQ6R3', 'ARBP9OOSHTCHU', 'A33AVAJ2PDY3EV', 'A17E79C6D8DWNP', 'A2VIGQ35RCS4UG', 'A21TJRUUN4KGV', 'A1PA6795UKMFR9'],
      'input_feed_document_id' => $feedDocID

    ]);
    
    try {
      $responseFeed = $this->sdk->feeds()->createFeed(
        $this->accessToken,
        $region,
        $specificationNewFeed
      );

    } catch (ApiException $e) {
      Log::channel('amazon')->error($e->getResponseBody());
    }
```

What could be problem?